# Custom scrollTo Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, if-statement, scroll

I'm making a custom scrollTo() function.
My function is:

```
function scrollTo(wait, scroll, time) {
    if (scroll == 'top' || scroll == 'Top') {
        if (wait == 0) {
            wait = 1;
        }
        $('html, body').delay(wait).animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, time);
    }
    else if (scroll === 'bottom' || scroll == 'Bottom') {
        time = time + 6000;
        $('html, body').delay(wait).animate({
            scrollTop: 60000
        }, time);
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').delay(wait).animate({
            scrollTop: scroll
        }, time);
    }
}
```

With an HTML that I just used really quick:

```
  <div onclick="scrollTo(0, 'Bottom', 1500);">To Bottom</div>

        <br><br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>
        br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>
        br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br
        <br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>
        <br><br><br><br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>
        br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>
        br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br
        <br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>br<br>
        <br><br>

   <div onclick="scrollTo(0, 'Top', 1500);">Top</div>
```

**Problem:**
When I click **To Bottom** it scrolls down fine, but then when I click **Top** it delays really long before going up. I don't know why though.

Any Solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know the plugin, but you set `wait = 1` only for scrolling to top.

Comment: Yes, because I was seeing if it was the .delay(wait). Don't mind that.

Comment: Why don't you just take a solution the works and satisfies your needs, like the [jQuery scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Comment: I think 'Re-inventing the wheel' is a good thing, despite common perception. There are not much things that were reinvented more often than the wheel. And look where we are now, without any stone wheels on our vehicles? Still you should know your limits and build on stuff that already exists, when it is stable and well adopted. If this stuff still hurts you, you can throw it away or modify it to your needs.

Comment: Next time just write `<div style="height:5000px"></div>` instead of all those `<br>` tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer, but I would like to ask you to slightly modify code, so I could sleep peacefully.

```
function scrollTo(wait, scroll, time) {
    var animatedScroll = function (lag, pixels, timeSpan) {
        $('html, body').delay(lag).animate({
            scrollTop: pixels
        }, timeSpan);
    },
        scrollCmd = scroll.toLowerCase();

    switch (scrollCmd) {
    case 'top':
        animatedScroll(wait === 0 ? 1 : wait, 0, time);
        break;
    case 'bottom':
        animatedScroll(wait, 60000, time + 6000);
        break;
    default:
        animatedScroll(wait, scroll, time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your page isn't really 60000 pixels long. When you click "To Bottom" it actually reaches the end of the page quite quickly, but it's really still animating invisibly. Then when you click "To Top" it's still animating invisibly, until you get to the real page height, at which point it starts scrolling normally.

Answer (score 2):

You should animate to `$('body').height()`. Currently the browser is too "zealous" and tries to scroll down even further (`60000` might be "large enough" but it calculates the animation steps wrongly because the page isn't that high).

Plus, you're adding 6 seconds when scrolling down - that makes the next click wait that additional time, since there is an animation queue which executes the animations in order of when they are added.

Also, use `===` and consider generalising it all (you have three bits of code which are almost all the same).

Lastly, I don't know why to delay things for 1 millisecond - it is not noticeable and it has no purpose (if you pass `0` for wait, I'd guess you also expect it not to wait).

http://jsfiddle.net/67RBH/2/

```
function scrollTo(wait, scroll, time) {
    var amount = scroll.toLowerCase(),
        pixels = amount === "top"    ? 0                  :
                 amount === "bottom" ? $('body').height() :
                 scroll;

    $('html, body').delay(wait).animate({
        scrollTop: pixels
    }, time);
}
```